# Access denied. You must have write or admin access

Tags: python, authentication, github, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

Dear stackoverflow community, i'am currently developing a plugin with Python which extract data  (payload) about developers activity on repositories (push, pull requests) from bitbucket using webhooks. In my python script , i am trying to access to the patch and diffstat url's (Bitbucket API)  content to extract data about files changes.

here example of the url's:

https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/username/projectname/patch/cac0848613fea833316fcf7d87da9f80a5a2174e

https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/username/projectname/diffstat/c6899a0a271db82790bf57de35dbbafb099417e4

But when the repository is private i cant access to the content of these web pages. If in the owner change private to public everything is okey but he can't change it for privacy so my question is how can access to these url's in my python script using the authentication? How can i authenticate via the script python knowing that i have write access on the repository?

thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need a token. From [the bitbucket docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/personal-access-tokens-939515499.html)

> Creating personal access tokens
>
> To create a personal access token:
>
> 1. Go to Profile picture > Manage account > Personal access tokens.
> 2. Click Create a token.
> 3. Set the token name, permissions, and expiry.